# C++ map start search from iterator position

Tags: c++, stl, find

My question is the following:

After using find on a std::map to get an iterator pointed to the desired element pair, is it possible to reuse that iterator on subsequent find()'s to take advantage of knowing that the elements im looking for afterwards are close to the first found element? Something like:

```
std::map<key, value> map_elements;
std::map<key, value>::iterator it;

it = map_elements.find(some_key);
it = it.find(a_close_key)
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not complete about how far Item1(found by map::find) can be far from Item2. In some case its more effecient to make new `map::find`; in some cases you can just iterate your iterator to find where your second item can be. Using just search `map::find` it will be O(log n) complexity and it can be around 10-20 steps.

So, if you know your Item2 is not so far, you can just iterate `it` iterator to find it out. Most important thing here is how to check you must stop search. `std::map` uses `std::less<T>` by default to arrange items, so it can be used to find out container is not containing Item2 at all. Something like this(not tested):

```
std::map<key, value> map_elements;
std::map<key, value>::iterator it, it2;

it2 = it = map_elements.find(some_key);
bool found=false;
while( it2!=map_elements.end() && !(a_close_key < it2->first) ) {
   if( !(a_close_key < it2->first) && !(it2->first < a_close_key) ) {
      //Equivalency is not ==, but its what used in std::map
      found=true;
      break;
   }
   it2++;
}
if( found ) {
   //.... use it2
}
```

Inside `if( found )` block your iterator `it2` value should be same as if you called [`map_elements.lower_bound(a_close_key)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/lower_bound/)

Comment: Its a pitty c++ does not provide an elegant way for map::find() to start on a given iterator...It looks like I will take your advice and interate myself on the map. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, still a SO newbie ;) tks for warning!

Answer (score 3):

If you're sure it's *really* nearby, you could use `std::find` (instead of `map::find`) to do a linear search for the item. If it's within approximately log(N) items of the current position, this is likely to be a win (where N is the number of items in the map).

Also note that you'll have to figure out whether you want a search before or after the current position, and specify `current`, `end()` if it's after, and `begin(), current` if it's before. If it's before, you'll want to do a reverse search (`find_end`, if memory serves) since the target is presumably close to the end of that range.

Comment: This is an elegant solution... just sad it does not take advantage of the list being ordered, and as such, in a "infinite list", it would iterate over all items if no element is found...which is worse than map::find. Thumbs up because it can be useful for someone else, thank you! PS: sorry, i have no reputation to vote...